# shard-query: Parallel updates without sharded database?

Tags: mysql, sharding

I'm using mysql. I have a table that I want to update in parallel but do not want to shard across multiple machines.

Can I use shard-query to do this? I tried partitioning the table and executing a query through shard-query, but it did not appear to execute in parallel using the workers.

Comment: What are you updating the table in parallel with?  I feel like a couple details are missing, but I'm unfamiliar with DB sharding in general.

Comment: shard-query: http://shardquery.com . A tool in the application layer than uses gearmand to execute queries as parallel jobs

Comment: So, you just want to update multiple rows in parallel with the same or other queries in that same table?  The basic toolkit ought to have an example for things like that.  I agree, shardquery.com is a bit odd in layout, however you'll still probably have better luck posting a comment there than here...

Comment: I contacted the creator. He said that for mysql 5.5 and below, it only executes parallel queries for tables partitioned by range and list, not hash. I am using mysql 5.5 and was partitioning by hash.